# GraphQL: why must destructure both in arg and function for this example?

Tags: graphql

In resolver I use lodash method 'find', if I code as:

```
user: (_, { _id }) => find(users, _id ),
```

I get null as result while should not, it happens that I must destructure again:

```
user: (_, { _id }) => find(users, { _id }),
```

Why is this? I thought that destructuring happens once and then the named argument is passed into the function, how to understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is not [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) but rather just shorthand syntax for [object initialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

This

```
find(users, { _id })
```

is equivalent to

```
find(users, { _id: _id })
```

it's just more succinct. In both cases, you are creating an object with a property named `_id` and setting the value of that property to an existing variable, which happens to also be named `_id`. If the property and variable names match, the shorthand syntax can be used.